# How can I add an element to a list using the delete1() predicate in prolog?

Tags: prolog, addition

I need to add an element to a list using the delete1 predicate that I have written:

```
delete1(H,[H|T],T).
delete1(H,[D|X],[D|Y]):-delete1(H,X,Y).
```

How can I do that? Well, I know how to delete element but can't figure out how to add an element there. I need to show all the possible lists that will be the result of adding 56 to [x,y,z,a] list. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If they are well-programmed, Prolog predicates can run "backwards":

**`f(X,Y)` should be read as `X` is related to `Y` via `f`.**

- Given an `x`, on can compute the `Y` (possibly several `Y` via backtracking): `f(x,Y)` is interpreted as **The set of `Y` such that: `f(x) = Y`.**
- Given a `y`, on can compute the `X` (possibly several `X` via backtracking): `f(X,y)` is interpreted as **The set of `X` such that: `f(X) = y`**.
- Given an `(x,y)`, on can compute the truth value: `f(x,y)` interpreted as *true* if (but not iff) `f(x) == y`.

(How many Prolog predicates are "well-programmed"? If there is a study about how many Prolog predicates written outside of the classroom can work bidirectionally I would like to know about it; my guess is most decay quickly into unidirectional functions, it's generally not worth the hassle of adding the edge cases and the test code to make predicates work bidirectionally)

The above works best if

- `f` is bijective, i.e.: "no information is thrown away when computing in either direction"
- the computation in both directions is tractable (having encryption work backwards is hard)

So, in this case:

`delete(Element,ListWith,ListWithout)` relates the three arguments `(Element,ListWith,ListWithout)` as follows:

**`ListWithout` is `ListWith` without `Element`.**

Note that "going forward" from `(Element,ListWith)` to `ListWithout` destroys information, namely the exact position of the deleted element, or even if there was one in the first place. BAD! NOT BIJECTIVE!

To make `delete1/3` run backwards we just have to:

```
?- delete1(56,L,[a,b,c]).
L = [56, a, b, c] ;
L = [a, 56, b, c] ;
L = [a, b, 56, c] ;
L = [a, b, c, 56] ;
```

There are four solutions to the reverse deletion problem.

And the program misses one:

```
L = [a, b, c]
```

or even a few more:

```
L = [56, a, b, 56, c]
```

etc.

As you can see, it is important to retain information!

Comment: I don't think this answer is as good as it could be. The `delete1` predicate from the question captures deletion of exactly one occurrence of `H` from the list. It can also be used for inserting exactly one occurrence. Your "missing solutions" apply to a different specification of deletion. Also it's not clear what point your discussion of bijectivity tries to make. `member/2` is not bijective (it's not even a function) and yet it's tremendously useful in all its modes. Relations are better than restricting ourselves to functions, bijective or otherwise.

Comment: Okay. I get it. Thank you both very much.